# how do I populate a column based on other two columns of the same table using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

My data is as below (table name is botdata)

[image: data]

Now i need to pivot this data to have Chatsession ID as rows and Metrics as columns. There has to be a new column Met014 which should show 1 only when Met003 and Met004 is 1. Below is the code I am using and the result I am getting. Everything else is fine but how do i populate Met014 correctly?

```
SELECT   ChatSessionID, 
 COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met001", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met001,
COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met002", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met002, 
COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met003", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met003,  
COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met004", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met004,  
COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met005", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met005,
  COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met006", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met006,
  COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met007", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met007,
COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met008", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met008,
COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met009", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met009,
COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met010", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met010,
COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met011", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met011,
COUNT(IF(Metrics = "Met012", Metrics, NULL)) AS Met012,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Metrics="Met003" And Metrics="Met004" THEN Metrics ELSE NULL END) AS Met014
 FROM
botdata b
WHERE
  b.Metrics BETWEEN "Met001" AND "Met014"
GROUP BY
  ChatSessionID;
```

[image: result]

Comment: It gives the desired output When I write a query `Select botdata.ChatSessionID,Met001,Met002,Met003,Met004,Met005,Met006,Met007,Met008,Met009,Met010,Met011,Met012,Met013,(IF(Met003<>0 and Met004<>0,1,0)) AS Met014 from botdata,` preceeding my query (mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this using `SUM()`.  I think you can then do what you want with `LEAST()`:

```
SELECT ChatSessionID, 
       SUM(Metrics = 'Met001') AS Met001,
       SUM(Metrics = 'Met002') AS Met002,
       . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .,
       SUM(Metrics = 'Met012') AS Met012,
       LEAST(SUM(Metrics = 'Met003'), SUM(Metrics = 'Met004')) AS Met014
FROM botdata b
GROUP BY ChatSessionID;
```

Comment: Sorry but No, it's not working. Still produces Met014 as "0" for all rows

Comment: I guess a Join would be needed. Since all the columns (Met001 to Met013) are generated during the Select statement, I think they are not available immediately for calculations within the same Select statement?

Comment: @DhimanJyotiSarmah . . . Hopefully your version didn't have the typo that this version had.

Comment: no there wasn't any typo but the Met014 still showed up only zeroes. As of now I am able to get the intended result as I mentioned in my comment on the original question, but I am not sure that is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns Met001 to Met013 can only take a value of 1, 0 or NULL, try something like this:

```
SELECT 
        T.*, (Met003 + Met004) = 2 AS Met014
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            ChatSessionID,
                Metrics = 'Met001' AS Met001,
                Metrics = 'Met002' AS Met002,
                Metrics = 'Met003' AS Met003,
                Metrics = 'Met004' AS Met004,
                Metrics = 'Met005' AS Met005,
                Metrics = 'Met006' AS Met006,
                Metrics = 'Met007' AS Met007,
                Metrics = 'Met008' AS Met008,
                Metrics = 'Met009' AS Met009,
                Metrics = 'Met010' AS Met010,
                Metrics = 'Met011' AS Met011,
                Metrics = 'Met012' AS Met012,
                Metrics = 'Met013' AS Met013
        FROM
            botdata b
        WHERE
            b.Metrics BETWEEN 'Met001' AND 'Met014'
        GROUP BY ChatSessionID) AS T;
```